# how to layout a Overlapping view like this

Tags: android, view

i just want to layout a overlapping view like this:

[image]

i think there are two ways to layout the view,one is cuting it into 5 parts,like below:

[image]

so we can control it ,but it is too complex.
another way is using framelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/state_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/state_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
            android:src="@drawable/state_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

but it can not perfectly fitting all size. anyone helps?

Comment: thank adnel for help editing

Comment: Use horizontal linear layout and specify `andoird:weight = 1` to all the imageviews. And set the width of each imageview to `0dp` like  `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Comment: yeah horizontal linear layout will divide the view into 3 parts.but it can not hold the view as the FrameLayout becasue the view like 1 and 2  have overlapping area

Comment: Relative layout will do it.

Comment: You can try using a LinearLayout and having negative values for the `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute on the second and third views

Comment: to Raphmclee and Karakuri. linearLayout and RelativiLayout is rectangle , so it will cause gap.just like https://github.com/sunpingji/test/blob/master/pic/a3.png